# Is there any alternative for ActiveXObject. I want to open command prompt on clicking a button in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function gen(){
var obj = new ActiveXObject('Wscript.Shell');
obj.run("cmd.exe");
}
```

The above code is working only in IE.Is there any alternate way to run it in chrome.Please Suggest.

Comment: you can't do that, why do you need the command line to execute from the browser?

Comment: Is there any way to open cmd in chrome?

Comment: short answer: no